# regex to replace characters in a string

Tags: java, regex, scala

I have a string like this `val str = "luckycore.util.BigNum("0")"`, the first five character of the string e.g `lucky` are dynamic and can change while rest of the string is fixed, what I was trying was to get output as
`luckyInt(0)` i.e replace all charaters except dynamic one with `Int` and also remove quotes around `0`, I tried using `replace` and `substring` methods and its working fine for me, but I want to get this output using `regex`, I tried but nothing is working, someone please help.

one more case is:

```
 input string = richardcore.util.BigNum("0")

 output string = richardInt(0)
```

Comment: "tried using replace and substring methods and its working fine for me, but I want to get this output using regex" <- Why? If you have a working solution use that. There is nothing magic about regular expressions and they are imho overused.

Comment: Find `^(.{5}).*?"(\d+)".*$` replace `$1Int($2)`

Comment: @both solution not woking

Comment: Oh, you want this [^(.*?)core.util.BigNum.*?"(\d+)".*$](https://regex101.com/r/OS6C7I/1)

Comment: let me try it out first..

Comment: @SayimKhan: Are you replacing a whole string? Or have you got a long string where you have several "lucky..." substrings? See http://ideone.com/JZMqWW

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, just this part `core.util.BigNum` replacing with Int and removing quotes around `0`, plz help, @sin's code not working in IDE

Comment: See http://ideone.com/JZMqWW. Maybe you even do not need `(\w*)` in the pattern and the replacement must be just `Int($1)` then. `val pat = """core\.util\.BigNum\("([0-9.,]+)"\)"""
 val s = """richardcore.util.BigNum("0")"""
 println(s.replaceAll(pat, "Int($1)"))`

Comment: @SayimKhan: Does my suggestiopn work as expected or do you mean `0` is hardcoded? Or is http://ideone.com/yazyXB what you'd like?

Comment: "the first five character" Given your second example, it's not fixed at 5, it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for Regex, you can simply do it:

```
val str = """luckycore.util.BigNum("0")"""
val l = str.replace(str.substring(str.indexOf("core"),str.indexOf("(")).trim,"Int").replace("\"","")
```

Comment: as long as the dynamic part can never contain "core". Maybe `lastIndexOf`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Regex `([a-z]{5})(core\.util\.BigNum\(\"0\"\))` and then replace the String with the **first captured Group**.

You can play with this regex at https://regex101.com/r/1DhgLo/1

I am not familiar with Scala or Java. But the Regex should be pretty much remain the same.

Comment: not wokring, I wanted a working solution, u just answered by asking the same question

Comment: Do you think Regex is not working or the java/scala code is not working ?

Comment: @SayimKhan - Which input values is it failing ?

Comment: same as typed in above question

Comment: If you open the link, it will show you both the input you specified in questions to be matching. I am not sure what is not working for you..

Comment: as soon as u click on subttution in https://regex101.com/r/1DhgLo/1, it does work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, there is no need for Regex. You can define a simple function (in Scala) as follows:

```
// Replace substring trailing after the first n characters 
def replaceTail(s: String, n: Int, tail: String) = {
  s.substring(0, n) + tail
}

val str1 = """luckycore.util.BigNum("0")"""
replaceTail(str1, 5, "Int(0)")
res1: String = luckyInt(0)

val str2 = """richardcore.util.BigNum("0")"""
replaceTail(str2, 7, "Int(0)")
res2: String = richardInt(0)
```

Comment: If the OP always knows what the dynamic part is (or just its length), it is of course trivial.  So it's a safe assumption the dynamic part is not known, so something slightly more flexible is needed.